# Conflicting trait implementations for types that clearly already implement the trait

Tags: rust

I'm working with webassembly so I need to fetch the pointer to a buffer. In the case where `T` is just `AsRef<[f32]>` (that is, it can be converted to a slice if I'm understanding correctly), I have solved it like this:

```rust
#[derive(TS, Serialize)]
pub struct PtrBufF32(usize);

impl<T> From<T> for PtrBufF32
    where T: AsRef<[f32]>
{
    fn from(f32arr: T) -> Self {
        let slc: &[f32] = f32arr.as_ref();
        let ptr: *const f32 = slc.as_ptr();
        Self(ptr as usize)
    }
}
```

I had help from another stack overflow user to understand what's going on -- as far as I'm understanding, this means "for any `T` that can be converted to a refence of `&[f32]` (that is, a slice), then we can implement this trait. The result is simply the pointer to the start of the slice of course.

But then in addition to implementing for anything that can be represented as `&[f32]`, we need to implement for any *collection* of things that can be represented by `&[f32]`. Like, if my type `T` implements `Into<&[f32]>`, then I can implement the type for any `AsRef<[T]>`, right? And so on. Any collection of *those* also implements it. So I thought:

```rust
impl<T> From<T> for PtrBufF32
    where T: AsRef<[dyn Into<PtrBufF32>]>
{
    fn from(f32arr: T) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

But no… apparently those are "conflicting implementations" somehow?

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<memory::ptrbuf::PtrBufF32>` for type `memory::ptrbuf::PtrBufF32`
```

Yet, if I try to `PtrBufF32::from(vec![T])` and `T` implements `Into<AsRef<[f32]>>`, it doesn't let me. So clearly it's not conflicting, is it?

Thanks

Comment: `dyn Into` is unsized and cannot appear in a slice. You probably want `U: Into<PtrBuf32>`

Comment: But then `U` is not constrained

Answer (score 0):

As long as you implemented conversion for undefined list of types you should think a little bit more widely.
Imagine some type `ForeignType`, that implements both `Into<PtrBufF32>` and `AsRef<[f32]>`. Then if you call `PtrBufF32::from(my_foreign_type)`, compiler cannot decide which of two implementation he must use.